# how do i use the data i get back from getJSON

Tags: jquery, json, api

I am new to jquery (and all programming), so I am trying to start simple by making one request and then putting that request on the screen.

Nothing happens when I view this file in my browser. I am expecting it to put the name on my screen. That's all I want to do, ask a question and put the answer on my screen. I am probably doing this the complete wrong way, so I am open to all suggestions!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script type="application/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<script>
$.getJSON('http://openapi.etsy.com/v2/teams/8787?method=GET&api_key=appkey&fields=name',function (data) {
    $('#TeamName').html(data.results[0].name);
})
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="TeamName"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I am using my appkey where it says appkey, i just didn't know if i should post it here.

Comment: what do you get as a response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server must return data in JSON format. Does it?

Also, print out the 'data' in your function to see if it's what you expect:

```
var output = '';
for (property in data) {
  output += property + ': ' + data[property]+'; ';
}
alert(output);
```

Take a look at this example:
http://www.jquery4u.com/json/ajaxjquery-getjson-simple/#.UCPgHqOPZnQ

Comment: Thank you. I tried adding that in but it didn't give me an alert.

Comment: this is how i added it, is it correct?<script type="application/javascript">
$.getJSON('http://openapi.etsy.com/v2/teams/8787?method=GET&api_key=appkey&fields=name',function (data) {
    $('#TeamName').html(data.results[0].name);
 var output = '';
for (property in data) {
  output += property + ': ' + data[property]+'; ';
}
alert(output);
})
</script>

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `.ajax` and not `.getJson` with `dataType: 'json'`. I had the same issue just the other day.